# Monitor CUDA function

Tags: functions, map, cudalink, monitoring

Is there a way to monitor CUDA function without bringing much performance reduction. 
For example, `Map` can be monitored by `Map[(monitor++;f),expr]`. However, CUDAMap does not support this kind of function.